# XAMPP offline keeps trying to connect to online site, why?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce, xampp

This is for a woocommerce site. I pulled the DB and the files locally onto my machine. I do have an SSL but I dont think that is the issue. When I run it locally I get the index page, which is under construction. The minute I try to login to the back admin part of wocommerce it immediately goes to the live URL online. How do I prevent this. I tried renaming the .htaccess thinking it was a redirect but it made no difference. If I shut the internet connection down, it still tries to reach out to the URL but says no internet connection available. Thanks.

Comment: If you didn't make any modifications, then it will probably still have the live system's URL in the database ...

Comment: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214580498-Change-the-WordPress-Site-URL